# Property management

Tags: javascript, angular.js

I was looking to see if anyone could help me come up with a cleaner/DRY methods in duplicate of doing something like this?

I would like to get the features that repeats in the 2 controllers to generalize my code.

```
var propertiesModule = angular.module('app.properties', []);

propertiesModule.controller('PropertiesCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'PropertiesService', 'ApplicationService', 'PlatformService', 'Page', function ($scope, $routeParams, PropertiesService, ApplicationService, PlatformService, Page) {

    Page.setTitle("Properties");
    $scope.platform = $routeParams.platform;

    $scope.platforms = [];

    $scope.on_edit_platform = function (platform_name) {
        /* Reset unit choice */
        $scope.unit = undefined;
    };

    $scope.add_platform = function (platform_name) {
        if (!_.contains($scope.platforms, platform_name)) {
            $scope.platforms.push(platform_name);
        }
    };

    $scope.delete_platform = function (platform) {
        //Might be a bit tricky
    };

    $scope.on_edit_unit = function (unit) {

        PropertiesService.getPropertiesMergedWithModel("properties#" + $scope.application.name + "#" + $scope.application.version + "#" + $scope.platform + "#" + unit.name, unit.modelNamespaces).then(function (properties) {
            $scope.properties = properties;

        });
    };

    $scope.save_properties = function (properties) {
        PropertiesService.save(properties).then(function (properties) {
            PropertiesService.getModel($scope.unit.modelNamespaces).then(function (model) {
                $scope.properties = properties.mergeWithModel(model);
            });
        });
    };

    $scope.on_concat_plateformes = function () {
        var a = $scope.platforms.concat($scope.platformsCible);
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
            for (var j = i + 1; j < a.length; ++j) {
                if (a[i] === a[j])
                    a.splice(j--, 1);
            }
        }
        return a;
    };

    /* Get the application */
    ApplicationService.get($routeParams.application, $routeParams.version).then(function (application) {
        $scope.application = application;
        /* If unit was mentionned in the route, try to find it */
        /* If it does not exist show error */

        if ($routeParams.unit) {

            var actual_unit = _.find(application.units, function (unit) {
                return unit.name === $routeParams.unit;
            });

            if (_.isUndefined(actual_unit)) {
                $.notify("La brique technique mentionee dans l'url n'existe pas", "error");
            } else {
                $scope.unit = actual_unit;
                $scope.on_edit_unit(actual_unit);
            }
        }
        ;
    }, function (error) {
        $.notify(error.data, "error");
    });

    /* Find all the platforms */
    PlatformService.get($routeParams.application, $routeParams.version).then(function (platforms) {
        $scope.platforms = platforms;
    }).then(function () {
        /* If platform was mentionned in the route, try to find it or add it */
        if ($scope.platform) $scope.add_platform($scope.platform);
    });

}]);

propertiesModule.controller('PropertiesCompareCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'PropertiesService', 'ApplicationService', 'PlatformService', 'Page', function ($scope, $routeParams, PropertiesService, ApplicationService, PlatformService, Page) {

    Page.setTitle("Comparer Properties par versions");
    $scope.platform = $routeParams.platform;
    $scope.platforms = [];
    $scope.platformsIdentique = [];
    var propertiesSources;

    $scope.on_edit_unit = function (unit) {

        PropertiesService.getPropertiesMergedWithModel("properties#" + $scope.application.name + "#" + $scope.application.version + "#" + $scope.platform + "#" + unit.name, unit.modelNamespaces).then(function (properties) {
            $scope.properties = properties;
            unit.modelNamespaces = ["app#" + $scope.applicationCible.name + "#" + $scope.applicationCible.version + "#" + unit.name + "", "technos#" + $scope.platform + "#" + $scope.applicationCible.version];
            PropertiesService.getPropertiesMergedWithModel("properties#" + $scope.applicationCible.name + "#" + $scope.applicationCible.version + "#" + $scope.platform + "#" + unit.name, unit.modelNamespaces).then(function (propertiesCible) {

                var tab1 = [];

                for (var i = 1; i <= $scope.properties.key_value_properties.length - 1; i++) {

                    tab1.push({
                        key: $scope.properties.key_value_properties[i].name,
                        value: $scope.properties.key_value_properties[i].value
                    });
                }

                var tab2 = [];
                for (var i = 1; i <= propertiesCible.key_value_properties.length - 1; i++) {
                    tab2.push({
                        key: propertiesCible.key_value_properties[i].name,
                        value: propertiesCible.key_value_properties[i].value
                    });
                }

                var tab1 = _.sortBy(tab1, 'key');
                var tab2 = _.sortBy(tab2, 'key');

                var obj1 = arrayToObject(tab1);
                var obj2 = arrayToObject(tab2);

                $scope.properties.differences = [];
                $scope.properties.absentInTab1 = [];
                $scope.properties.presentInTab1 = [];

                for (var i in obj1) {
                    if (typeof(obj2[i]) === 'undefined') {
                        // presentInTab1.push({ key: i, oldValue: obj1[i], newValue: null });
                        $scope.properties.presentInTab1.push({name: i, valueRef: obj1[i], valueCible: null});
                    }
                    else if (obj1[i] !== obj2[i]) {
                        //differences.push({ key: i, oldValue: obj1[i], newValue: obj2[i] });
                        $scope.properties.differences.push({name: i, valueRef: obj1[i], valueCible: obj2[i]});
                    }
                }
                for (var i in obj2) {
                    if (typeof(obj1[i]) === 'undefined') {
                        // absentInTab1.push({ key: i, oldValue: null, newValue: obj2[i] });
                        $scope.properties.absentInTab1.push({name: i, valueRef: null, valueCible: obj2[i]});
                    }
                }

                $scope.properties.groups = [
                    { name: 'Diff Version ' + $scope.application.version + ' / Version ' + $scope.applicationCible.version,
                        members: $scope.properties.differences
                    },
                    { name: 'Propriétés en + sur Version ' + $scope.application.version + ' / Version ' + $scope.applicationCible.version,
                        members: $scope.properties.presentInTab1
                    },
                    { name: 'Propriétés - sur Version ' + $scope.application.version + ' / Version ' + $scope.applicationCible.version,
                        members: $scope.properties.absentInTab1
                    }
                ];
            }, function (error) {
            });
        });
    };

    function arrayToObject(array) {
        var object = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            object[array[i].key] = array[i].value;
        }
        return object;
    }

    function dynamicSort(property) {
        var sortOrder = 1;
        if (property[0] === "-") {
            sortOrder = -1;
            property = property.substr(1);
        }
        return function (a, b) {
            var result = (a[property] < b[property]) ? -1 : (a[property] > b[property]) ? 1 : 0;
            return result * sortOrder;
        }
    }


    ApplicationService.get($routeParams.application, $routeParams.version).then(function (application) {
        $scope.application = application;
        /* If unit was mentionned in the route, try to find it */
        /* If it does not exist show error */

        if ($routeParams.unit) {

            var actual_unit = _.find(application.units, function (unit) {
                return unit.name === $routeParams.unit;
            });

            if (_.isUndefined(actual_unit)) {
                $.notify("La brique technique mentionee dans l'url n'existe pas", "error");
            } else {
                $scope.unit = actual_unit;
                $scope.on_edit_unit(actual_unit);
            }
        }
        ;
    }, function (error) {
        $.notify(error.data, "error");
    });

    /*   Get the application cible for compare*/

    ApplicationService.get($routeParams.application, $routeParams.versionCible).then(function (applicationCible) {
        $scope.applicationCible = applicationCible;
        /* If unit was mentionned in the route, try to find it*/
        /* If it does not exist show error*/
        if ($routeParams.unit) {
            var actual_unit = _.find(applicationCible.units, function (unit) {
                return unit.name === $routeParams.unit;
            });

            if (_.isUndefined(actual_unit)) {
                $.notify("La brique technique mentionee dans l'url n'existe pas", "error");
            } else {
                $scope.unit = actual_unit;
                $scope.on_edit_unit(actual_unit);
            }
        }
        ;

    }, function (error) {
        $.notify(error.data, "error");
    });

    /* Find all the platforms */
    PlatformService.get($routeParams.application, $routeParams.version).then(function (platforms) {
        $scope.platforms = platforms;
    }).then(function () {
        /* If platform was mentionned in the route, try to find it or add it */
        if ($scope.platform) $scope.add_platform($scope.platform);
    });

    /* Find all the platforms cible */
    if ($routeParams.versionCible != null) {
        PlatformService.get($routeParams.application, $routeParams.versionCible).then(function (platforms) {
            var a = $scope.platforms;
            var b = platforms;
            a = a.sort()
            $scope.platformsIdentique = _.intersection(a, b)

        });
    }

}]);

propertiesModule.controller('PropertiesComparePlateformesCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'PropertiesService', 'ApplicationService', 'PlatformService', 'Page', function ($scope, $routeParams, PropertiesService, ApplicationService, PlatformService, Page) {

    Page.setTitle("Comparer Application Plateformes");
    $scope.platform = $routeParams.platform;
    $scope.platforms = [];
    var propertiesSources;

    $scope.enableCompare = function () {
        return !($scope.mySelectRef && $scope.mySelectCible);
    };

    /*   Get the application cible for compare*/
    ApplicationService.get($routeParams.application, $routeParams.version).then(function (applicationPlateformes) {
        $scope.applicationPlateformes = applicationPlateformes;
        /* If unit was mentionned in the route, try to find it*/
        /* If it does not exist show error*/
        if ($routeParams.unit) {
            var actual_unit = _.find(applicationPlateformes.units, function (unit) {
                return unit.name === $routeParams.unit;
            });

            if (_.isUndefined(actual_unit)) {
                $.notify("La brique technique mentionee dans l'url n'existe pas", "error");
            } else {
                $scope.unit = actual_unit;
                $scope.on_edit_unit(actual_unit);
            }
        }
        ;
    }, function (error) {
        $.notify(error.data, "error");
    });

    /* Find all the platforms */
    PlatformService.get($routeParams.application, $routeParams.version).then(function (platforms) {
        $scope.platforms = platforms;
    }).then(function () {
        /* If platform was mentionned in the route, try to find it or add it */
        if ($scope.platform) $scope.add_platform($scope.platform);
    });

    $scope.on_compare_plateformes = function (unit) {
        PropertiesService.getPropertiesMergedWithModel("properties#" + $scope.applicationPlateformes.name + "#" + $scope.applicationPlateformes.version + "#" + $scope.mySelectRef + "#" + unit.name, unit.modelNamespaces).then(function (propertiesRef) {
            $scope.properties = propertiesRef;
            PropertiesService.getPropertiesMergedWithModel("properties#" + $scope.applicationPlateformes.name + "#" + $scope.applicationPlateformes.version + "#" + $scope.mySelectCible + "#" + unit.name, unit.modelNamespaces).then(function (propertiesCible) {
                var tab1 = [];

                for (var i = 1; i <= $scope.properties.key_value_properties.length - 1; i++) {

                    tab1.push({
                        key: $scope.properties.key_value_properties[i].name,
                        value: $scope.properties.key_value_properties[i].value
                    });
                }

                var tab2 = [];
                for (var i = 1; i <= propertiesCible.key_value_properties.length - 1; i++) {
                    tab2.push({
                        key: propertiesCible.key_value_properties[i].name,
                        value: propertiesCible.key_value_properties[i].value
                    });
                }
                var tab1 = _.sortBy(tab1, 'key');
                var tab2 = _.sortBy(tab2, 'key');

                var obj1 = arrayToObject(tab1);
                var obj2 = arrayToObject(tab2);

                $scope.properties.differences = [];
                $scope.properties.absentInTab1 = [];
                $scope.properties.presentInTab1 = [];

                for (var i in obj1) {
                    if (typeof(obj2[i]) === 'undefined') {
                        // presentInTab1.push({ key: i, oldValue: obj1[i], newValue: null });
                        $scope.properties.presentInTab1.push({name: i, valueRef: obj1[i], valueCible: null});
                    }
                    else if (obj1[i] !== obj2[i]) {
                        //differences.push({ key: i, oldValue: obj1[i], newValue: obj2[i] });
                        $scope.properties.differences.push({name: i, valueRef: obj1[i], valueCible: obj2[i]});
                    }
                }
                for (var i in obj2) {
                    if (typeof(obj1[i]) === 'undefined') {
                        // absentInTab1.push({ key: i, oldValue: null, newValue: obj2[i] });
                        $scope.properties.absentInTab1.push({name: i, valueRef: null, valueCible: obj2[i]});
                    }
                }


                $scope.properties.groups = [
                    { name: 'Diff Plateforme ' + $scope.MySelectRef + ' / Plateforme ' + $scope.MySelectCible,
                        members: $scope.properties.differences
                    },
                    { name: 'Propriétés en + sur Plateforme ' + $scope.MySelectRef + ' / Plateforme ' + $scope.MySelectCible,
                        members: $scope.properties.presentInTab1
                    },
                    { name: 'Propriétés - sur Plateforme ' + $scope.MySelectRef + ' / Plateforme ' + $scope.MySelectCible,
                        members: $scope.properties.absentInTab1
                    }
                ];
            });
        });
    };

    function arrayToObject(array) {
        var object = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            object[array[i].key] = array[i].value;
        }
        return object;
    }

    function dynamicSort(property) {
        var sortOrder = 1;
        if (property[0] === "-") {
            sortOrder = -1;
            property = property.substr(1);
        }
        return function (a, b) {
            var result = (a[property] < b[property]) ? -1 : (a[property] > b[property]) ? 1 : 0;
            return result * sortOrder;
        }
    }
}]);

propertiesModule.directive('propertiesList', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            properties: '='
        },
        templateUrl: "properties/properties-list.html",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        }
    };
});

propertiesModule.directive('propertiesListCompare', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            properties: '='
        },
        templateUrl: "properties/properties-list-compare.html",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        }
    };
});

propertiesModule.factory('Properties', function () {

    var Properties = function (data) {

        angular.extend(this, {
            namespace: "",
            key_value_properties: [],
            iterable_properties: [],
            versionID: -1
        }, data);


        this.hasKey = function (name) {
            return _.some(this.key_value_properties, function (key) {
                return key.name === name;
            });
        };

        this.hasIterable = function (name) {
            return _.some(this.iterable_properties, function (key) {
                return key.name === name;
            });
        };

        this.mergeWithModel = function (model) {
            var me = this;
            /* Mark key_values that are in the model */
            _.each(this.key_value_properties, function (key_value) {
                key_value.inModel = model.hasKey(key_value.name);
            });

            _.each(this.iterable_properties, function (iterable) {
                iterable.inModel = model.hasIterable(iterable.name);
            });

            /* Add key_values that are only in the model */
            _(model.key_value_properties).filter(function (model_key_value) {
                return !me.hasKey(model_key_value.name);
            }).each(function (model_key_value) {
                me.key_value_properties.push({
                    name: model_key_value.name,
                    comment: model_key_value.comment,
                    value: "",
                    inModel: true
                });
            });

            _(model.iterable_properties).filter(function (model_iterable) {
                return !me.hasIterable(model_iterable.name);
            }).each(function (model_iterable) {
                me.iterable_properties.push({
                    name: model_iterable.name,
                    comment: model_iterable.comment,
                    fields: model_iterable.fields,
                    inModel: true
                });
            });

            return this;
        };

        this.toAppEntity = function () {
            return {
                namespace: this.namespace,
                versionID: this.versionID,
                key_value_properties: _.map(this.key_value_properties, function (kvp) {
                    return {
                        name: kvp.name,
                        comment: kvp.comment,
                        value: kvp.value
                    }
                }),
                iterable_properties: _.map(this.iterable_properties, function (ip) {
                    return {
                        name: ip.name,
                        comment: ip.comment,
                        fields: ip.fields
                    }
                })
            }
        }

    };

    return Properties;

});

propertiesModule.factory('PropertiesService', ['$http', 'Properties', function ($http, Properties) {

    return {
        getModel: function (namespaces) {
            var namespaces_as_string = _.isArray(namespaces) ? namespaces.join(",") : namespaces;
            return $http.get('rest/properties/model/' + encodeURIComponent(namespaces_as_string)).then(function (response) {
                return new Properties(response.data);
            }, function (error) {
                return new Properties({});
            });
        },
        get: function (namespace) {
            return $http.get('rest/properties/' + encodeURIComponent(namespace)).then(function (response) {
                return new Properties(response.data);
            }, function (error) {
                $.notify(error.data, "error");
                throw error;
            });
        },
        getPropertiesMergedWithModel: function (properties_namespace, model_namespaces) {
            var me = this;
            return this.getModel(model_namespaces).then(function (model) {

                return me.get(properties_namespace).then(function (properties) {
                    return properties.mergeWithModel(model);
                }, function (error) {
                    var properties = new Properties({namespace: properties_namespace});
                    return properties.mergeWithModel(model);
                });

            });
        },
        save: function (properties) {
            properties = properties.toAppEntity();
            if (properties.versionID < 0) {
                return $http.post('rest/properties/' + encodeURIComponent(properties.namespace), properties).then(function (response) {
                    $.notify("Les proprietes ont bien ete crees", "success");
                    return new Properties(response.data);
                }, function (error) {
                    $.notify(error.data, "error");
                });
            } else {
                return $http.put('rest/properties/' + encodeURIComponent(properties.namespace), properties).then(function (response) {
                    $.notify("Les proprietes ont bien ete mises a jour", "success");
                    return new Properties(response.data)
                }, function (error) {
                    $.notify(error.data, "error");
                });
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: It would help if you'd give a problem statement that explains what you are trying to do.  That way we can evaluate the code in light of the problem statement rather than having to figure out the problem you're solving from the code.

Comment: @Brythan I would like to get the features that repeats in the 3 controllers to generalize my code.

Comment: Which features?

Comment: @psaxton ApplicationService.get  PlatformService.get

Comment: Move the repeated logic from to the controllers into the service.

Comment: @psaxton can i use $scope in service .?

Comment: If you pass it as an argument to your function.

Comment: @psaxton i can't inject $scope into services, there is no such thing as a Singleton $scope.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18622/discussion-between-psaxton-and-mercer).

Comment: Jesus, you should really cut down the code so it's easier to write a review on. It's too massive, consider splitting it up into partial reviews.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short, nitpicking review:

- Here, there seems to be no good reason to choose `key` and `value` instead of `name` and `value`, it just seems like it makes things more complicated.

  ```
          var tab1 = [];

          for (var i = 1; i <= $scope.properties.key_value_properties.length - 1; i++) {

              tab1.push({
                  key: $scope.properties.key_value_properties[i].name,
                  value: $scope.properties.key_value_properties[i].value
              });
          }

          var tab2 = [];
          for (var i = 1; i <= propertiesCible.key_value_properties.length - 1; i++) {
              tab2.push({
                  key: propertiesCible.key_value_properties[i].name,
                  value: propertiesCible.key_value_properties[i].value
              });
          }
  ```

  could be

  ```
          var tab1 = $scope.properties.key_value_properties,
              tab2 = propertiesCible.key_value_properties;
  ```
- Also, mandatory bash on using French in variables names. Don't do it, `propertiesCible` -> `propertiesTarget`
- Consider using syntax sugar (in this example using shortcut variables) and remove useless comments, this

  ```
          $scope.properties.differences = [];
          $scope.properties.absentInTab1 = [];
          $scope.properties.presentInTab1 = [];

          for (var i in obj1) {
              if (typeof(obj2[i]) === 'undefined') {
                  // presentInTab1.push({ key: i, oldValue: obj1[i], newValue: null });
                  $scope.properties.presentInTab1.push({name: i, valueRef: obj1[i], valueCible: null});
              }
              else if (obj1[i] !== obj2[i]) {
                  //differences.push({ key: i, oldValue: obj1[i], newValue: obj2[i] });
                  $scope.properties.differences.push({name: i, valueRef: obj1[i], valueCible: obj2[i]});
              }
          }
          for (var i in obj2) {
              if (typeof(obj1[i]) === 'undefined') {
                  // absentInTab1.push({ key: i, oldValue: null, newValue: obj2[i] });
                  $scope.properties.absentInTab1.push({name: i, valueRef: null, valueCible: obj2[i]});
              }
          }
  ```

  could be

  ```
          var differences = $scope.properties.differences = [],
              absentInTab1 = $scope.properties.absentInTab1 = [],
              presentInTab1 = $scope.properties.presentInTab1 = [];

          for (var i in obj1) {
              if (typeof(obj2[i]) === 'undefined') {
                  presentInTab1.push({name: i, valueRef: obj1[i], valueCible: null});
              }
              else if (obj1[i] !== obj2[i]) {
                  differences.push({name: i, valueRef: obj1[i], valueCible: obj2[i]});
              }
          }
          for (var i in obj2) {
              if (typeof(obj1[i]) === 'undefined') {
                  absentInTab1.push({name: i, valueRef: null, valueCible: obj2[i]});
              }
          }
  ```
- I strive to never use `null` but `undefined` instead
- Be more ardent in reducing copy paste lines, the following seems a good example:

  ```
  save: function (properties) {
      properties = properties.toAppEntity();
      if (properties.versionID < 0) {
          return $http.post('rest/properties/' + encodeURIComponent(properties.namespace), properties).then(function (response) {
              $.notify("Les proprietes ont bien ete crees", "success");
              return new Properties(response.data);
          }, function (error) {
              $.notify(error.data, "error");
          });
      } else {
          return $http.put('rest/properties/' + encodeURIComponent(properties.namespace), properties).then(function (response) {
              $.notify("Les proprietes ont bien ete mises a jour", "success");
              return new Properties(response.data)
          }, function (error) {
              $.notify(error.data, "error");
          });
      }
  }
  ```

  you could try this:

  ```
  save: function (properties) {
      var createdMessage = 'Les proprietes ont bien ete crees',
          updatedMessage = 'Les proprietes ont bien ete mises a jour',
          message = properties.versionID < 0 ? createdMessage : updatedMessage;

      properties = properties.toAppEntity();
          return $http.put('rest/properties/' + encodeURIComponent(properties.namespace), properties).then(function (response) {
              $.notify( message  , "success");
              return new Properties(response.data)
          }, function (error) {
              $.notify(error.data, "error");
          });

  }
  ```
- You could reduce the vertical stretching in your code quite a bit by using `_.pick()`:

  ```
              return {
                  name: kvp.name,
                  comment: kvp.comment,
                  value: kvp.value
              }
  ```

  could be

  ```
              return _.pick( kvp, 'name', 'comment', 'value');
  ```